# Deep Cloning Backbone.js Models

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am working in jquery with backbone.js and running into the case where i need to duplicate models, but i need to do a deep copy on them so no references exist between the copies. Models can have other models as attributes. Models can have anon functions as attributes.

So i'm working on creating an algorithm that will deep clone most backbone models. I’m expecting that all bindings should be removed (for the new instance) during this copy so I’m not worried about trying to keep them.

Goals:

- Able to duplicate all simple variable (String, Int, float, etc) and store it into the new model, as the same name.

  - Done, using toJSON to create a new JSON object which can be passed to set(). This object only contains simple attributes, i.e. does not include attributes assigned to functions or other models.
- Able to duplicate the anon functions some variables will be assigned to, without knowing function/attribute names beforehand.

  - If I know the name of the attribute which is assigned to a function I can copy it. But if the model is new or unknown I don’t have that information.
- If an attribute is another backbone model, call the deep copy algorithm recursively on that attribute.

  - Not able to check if an attribute is a backbone model with native backbone methods, looking for a work around.

The simplified version of what I currently have is below:

```
/**
 * Performs a deep copy of a backbone.js model
 * All bindings for the copy are lost
 * @param orgModel - the original model to copy
 */
function deepCopyModel(orgModel)
{   
    var dupModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var orgAttributes= orgModel.toJSON();

    var keepAttr=_.keys(orgAttributes);
    //remove any special cases
    keepAttr=_.without( keepAttr , 'specialCase1', 'specialCase2' );
    //or keepAttr=_.difference(keepAttr, ['specialCase1', 'specialCase2'] );

    //remove undefined values
    keepAttr=_.filter(keepAttr,function(key) {
        return ( typeof(attributes[key])!="undefined" );
    });
    //grab the resulting list of attributes after filtering
    var result=_.pick(attributes,keepAttr);
    //assign attributes to the copy using set
    dupModel.set(result);

    //TODO: Implement deep copy of functions

    //TODO: Implement deep copy of inner models

        return dupModel;
}
```

Any help or insight you can give would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: out of curiosity why would you need to deep copy *functions*?

Comment: you cannot really deep-copy functions: inside saved state of closures is essentially opaque. Example: `function(y) { var x=y; return function() { x++; console.log(x); }; }`.

Comment: Hmmm... underscore's extend will copy both static properties and methods and everything on the prototype from one object to another. You can do this at definition or at run time. But I'm also curious as to why you want to do this because essentially what you're describing is inheritance.

Comment: Ok, i guess i misunderstood the meaning of copying functions. As long as the new model has access to the same functions as the old one, and will not clash variables between the two, i'm good.

Comment: Ok, the thing is, i need to have two instances of the same object. One that is bound to the UI. And one for a process done in the background. Any changes i need done on this background model i do not want reflected on the UI until after the process is done. And sometimes not even then. Two completely different instances are needed, just with the same information inside.

Comment: @DanielGradinjan, my answer below shows how you can have two separate objects (where one was spawned from the other) referencing the same function without one affecting the other!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery's `extend` method allows you to simply copy object properties from one to another.

Here's a contrived, but illustrative example. It even shows why you would not need to "deep" copy functions!

```
var someObj = {
    a : "a",
    b : 12345,
    c : {
        d : "d",
        e : "e"
    },
    f : function() {
        alert(this.a);
    }
};

//copy from original to new empty object
var deepCopy = $.extend(true, {}, someObj);

deepCopy.a = "deepCopy.a";
deepCopy.c.d = "deepCopy.c.d";

alert("someObj is not affected when deep copying: " + someObj.c.d);
alert("deepCopy is entirely distinct when deep copying: " + deepCopy.c.d);

deepCopy.f();    
someObj.f();
```

Here's a fiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/S6p3F/3/

Running this code you will see that `someObj` and `deepCopy` are identical in structure but distinct objects.

As you can see, deep copying of functions is not required as the `this` reference is bound to whatever object the function is applied to. This is becausein javascript, calling a function as `deepCopy.f()` is functionally equivalent to `deepCopy.f.call(deepCopy)`. A more illustrative example:

```
function someFunction() {
    alert(this.someProperty);
}

var a = {
        someProperty: "a's property"
    },
    b = {
        someProperty: "b's property"
    };

someFunction.call(a);
someFunction.call(b);
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S6p3F/2/

Comment: if you supply `true` as a first param to `extend` it does indeed do a deep copy. Example updated to reflect this. As for closures etc. anyone with a reasonable understanding of JS will understand this. My point was not that it would work in all circumstances, but that copying the function reference is usually all that is needed.

Comment: I've commented on some other answer before about jQuery's extend. jQuery does some testing to see what kind of object an object is before it copies it.  I have some significant doubts about this answer.  Go ahead, search the jQuery source for this line:  `if ( deep && copy && ( jQuery.isPlainObject(copy) || (copyIsArray = jQuery.isArray(copy)) ) ) {`

Comment: How do you intend to handle cloning an array or backbone collection?  Shallow copy (extend) just changes the base reference, but not the references of the array elements.

Comment: Backbone uses underscore which comes with its own `extend()` function. Backbone models already use this function.

Comment: I'm getting an infinite loop doing this with a Backbone model.

Comment: @ChristopherMasser presumably there is a circular reference in your models. e.g. A refers to B, and vice versa. Either shallow copy or take some other approach

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) as Underscore drop-in replacement, you can also use [_.cloneDeep](http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep)

```
var newModel = new MyModel(_.cloneDeep(oldModel.toJSON());
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as desired for models and collections nested within the oldModel. You'll end up with an `attributes` object as an attribute, etc.